# Remove Touch LIstener from scene at a specific point

Tags: andengine

how to remove SceneTouchListner at a specific point?

I am Working on a Endless Runner Game. my player is jumping onSceneTouchListner
when player is collide with a barrier i want to remove TouchListner because i attached a particle effact that burns my player.

Answer (score -1):

finally I got Solution ..............I am Creating a new 
IOnSceneTouchListener tv= new IOnSceneTouchListener() {

```
                @Override
                public boolean onSceneTouchEvent(Scene pScene, TouchEvent pSceneTouchEvent) 
                {
                    if(pSceneTouchEvent.isActionUp())
                    {
                        player.animate(new long[]{200, 200, 200},9,11, true);   
                        return true;
                    }
                    return false;
                }
            };
```

and the just write scene.setonsceneTouchListner(tv);.